# How to get multiple table in Entity Framework Core?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I make a dashboard for log viewer system.

I use .net core 1.0 and Entity Framework Core. The log datum are in each tables. And the each tables were named by datetime like [2018_01_01] , [2018_01_02].
I have no idea how to design DBContext class of that log table(dbset) datum.
Because the datum counts and names are dynamically changed. (1 table per 1 day)

But all the log tables have same column format.

How should i design dbcontext class and get those multiple table by entity framework core? If this is not possible to use entity for this case maybe i must use sql...

Comment: Do you have any opportunity to change the database? That's a very bad table design. You might have to write a stored procedure that dynamically works out which tables you want. Or build that in your app.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid No.. Unfortunately all the system is already work by that design.So i can't change that. It seems to be that if the all logs are in same table then the search speed is to slow, so first developer will designed like that (Just i guess)

Comment: Putting data into seperate tables is a very amatuerish effort to improve performance but that's beside the point - just understand that this is bad table design. Anyway.. is a new table created every day? Do you report in just todays data or do you need a trend? You are going to have to build the SQL dynamically and run it. For example `select col1, col2, '2018-01-01' from [2018_01_01] UNION ALL select col1, col2, '2018-01-02' from [2018_01_02] ` will combine the data for you

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Thanks for answering. 
Well... for example case If the log viewer select(get) data for just a day or less then 7 days. Then it will check all log datum. (because all datum are just in 1 table.)

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Then i use dynamic sql like your answer, then can i mapping that sql's result set in to my model class (or entity)?

Comment: If one days data is in one table then to get seven days you need to union together seven tables in your app logic. If I was doing this I would probably use a trigger or procedure to load all of the different tables into one table at the database layer. Then your app layer logic is _way_ simpler

Comment: Yes any SQL statement can be mapped into a class. Just create a class that matches the resulting columns then load the result into a object of that type `MyClass t = db.Database.SqlQuery<MyClass>("sqlquery");`

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Wow~ Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of a way to dynamically add entities to LINQ, let alone refer to this automatically in code. So here are some solutions:

### Application level solution:

1. Work out the data  range you will be selecting
2. Dynamically build a string like this

:

```
SELECT *, CAST('2018-01-01' AS DATE) FROM [2018-01-01] UNION ALL
SELECT *, CAST('2018-01-02' AS DATE) FROM [2018-01-02] UNION ALL
SELECT *, CAST('2018-01-03' AS DATE) FROM [2018-01-03] UNION ALL
SELECT *, CAST('2018-01-04' AS DATE) FROM [2018-01-04]
```

3. Run the string against a class that matches the columns returned

:

```
MyClass t = db.Database.SqlQuery<MyClass>("sqlquery");
```

You are probably going to run into various issues here when you get too many tables.

### Database Level Solutions

- Use DDL and DML triggers to automatically write the data to a single table and just use that single table
- Create a view that has to be altered every day that contains the `union` select statements above

### Ideal Solution

Redesign the database

I realise this is not an option but you should know that you have to implement extra effort and coding because this database is not designed properly